# Need image to fill height of div

Tags: html, css

I did do many searched for this but anything I try is not working. I need the image to fill the height of the div, the extra image can get off to the right. But anything I try is not working... What am I missing? I don't want to see any red in this box but yet keep the proportions of the image. Thank You!

https://jsfiddle.net/rhwx23o4/6/

```
<figure id="main-img"><img src="http://http://www.kimwilddesigns.com/web-lesson/4-4_start/images/hp_main-img_1.jpg"/></figure>

figure#main-img {
width:100%;
min-height: 200px;
background-color: red;
    overflow: hidden;

}
figure#main-img img {
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
}
```

Comment: I would use a `background-image:url(yourImg.png); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center; background-size:contain;`... or the shorthand `background:center / contain no-repeat url(yourImg.png);` if you want to keep the background color the same, for this instead of an `<img />`

Comment: I moved it as a background image like you suggest and with media queries to adjust the height this was a good solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a little bit of work around. On the breakpoint i.e here `840px` I gave property `display:none` to your image and gave outer `div` background of same image.

> **NOTE**: In media query I had to hard-code the `max-width`. It won't be same for all images.

```css
figure#main-img {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: hidden;
}

figure#main-img img {
  width: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 840px) {
  div {
    background: url('http://www.kimwilddesigns.com/web-lesson/4-4_start/images/hp_main-img_1.jpg');
    height: 200px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
  }
  img {
    display: none;
    overflow: auto;
    min-height: 200px;
    max-height: 200px;
  }
}

figure {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<figure id="main-img">
  <div><img src="http://www.kimwilddesigns.com/web-lesson/4-4_start/images/hp_main-img_1.jpg" /></div>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `height: 100vh;`

https://jsfiddle.net/rhwx23o4/65/

```
figure#main-img {
width:100%;
height: 100vh;
display: block;
background-color: red;
    overflow: hidden;

}
figure#main-img img {
    height: 100vh;
    object-fit: contain;
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that this won't work in IE. This includes anyone using Win 7 (my workplace) or 8. https://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit

Answer (score 0):

Check this https://jsfiddle.net/rhwx23o4/76/

Added `height="100%"` and `width="100%"` to the image tag

Comment: Hi, that didn't do anything for me? still seeing the same thing https://jsfiddle.net/rhwx23o4/44/

Comment: Check this out. I had missed out on the body styling. Also only specify the height for the image as 100%. Also added width and height for the container `figure` element   https://jsfiddle.net/rhwx23o4/76/

Comment: Don't make people leave StackOverflow to find your whole answer. Your answer should stand on it's own without the need to go to a third party site. User the `<>` button in the Answer editor to include a StackSnippet in your answer. It's like JsFiddle but integrated to StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS. Is this what you want? I gave the image a display property of block and changed the object-fit to cover instead of contain.

```
figure#main-img {
  width:100%;
  min-height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
figure#main-img img {
  display: block;
  min-height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Comment: Yes exactly thank you! Is there a way to get the image to maintain the left align position, rather that keep it centered when scaling the window?

Comment: It should be noted that this won't work in IE. This includes anyone using Win 7 (my workplace) or 8. https://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `display: flex;` in `<figure>` like this [codepen](https://codepen.io/tusharshukla/pen/jzKvbr):

```
figure#main-img {
    width:100%;
    min-height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
}
```

> Flex has magical powers to adjust content within it.

In case you do not want `<figure>` to take up whole screen width (which it would being a block element), you can change its display to `display: inline-flex;` and then add a certain width/max-width to it.

Comment: I will try this. What properties would figure#main-img img get? Thank you!

Comment: none as per your requirement, you can check the codepen I've mentioned to see this code in action

Comment: Don't make people leave StackOverflow to find your whole answer. Your answer should stand on it's own without the need to go to a third party site. User the `<>` button in the Answer editor to include a StackSnippet in your answer. It's like Codepen but integrated to StackOverflow

Comment: @JonP The relevant part of the answer is already included in the answer. The codepen is just for case OP wants to fiddle more. Apart from this, choosing to share code snippet on codepen was purely based on my comfort and habit of the platform. But I'll take care of this next time onward. Thanks for pointing out.